# Duplicate questions by same user

Tags: discussion, duplicates

[Ashwin](https://askubuntu.com/users/160003/ashwin) joined and immediately asked the same question twice within 4 hours:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/297351/ubuntu-13-04-is-not-booting

https://askubuntu.com/questions/297406/ubuntu-13-04-not-booting-after-upgrade-from-12-10

I tried to flag the second one as a duplicate, but I can't get the first one to appear in the duplicate-of list no matter what I search for. I suspect this list filters out the same author's own posts, on the assumption that duplicates would only occur if the author was unaware that the question had been asked before. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I think you couldn't flag them duplicates because you can now only link a dupe to a question that has an upvoted or accepted answer. (correct me if I'm wrong)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, just copy the link from the first one and paste it in to the search box in the duplicate form that shows when you press to close to vote it as a duplicate.

[image]

You can search parameters, enter the direct link to a post or the ID number of the post you want to link as duplicate.

Comment: D'oh! I did actually try that, but for some reason I thought the "Flag Question" button was disabled; nope, it was fine. Thanks!

Comment: Flag should not really be used to mark duplicates of posts, with a bit of reputation users can start voting to close questions, vote to close is what needs to be used when you want to close a question as a dupe. In case you cannot vote yet just leave a comment under the posts with the link to the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation. So should the flag-as-duplicate feature simply never be used? It sounds like you're saying this was a good idea on paper but has not met the needs of moderators well in practice. In this case, leaving a comment felt redundant because the question itself already admitted to being a duplicate and linked to the original.

Comment: Yes, in this case its redundant to be explaining and voting for closure as a dupe. The flag for duplicate will be mostly used as a last resort, mostly if the dupe is evident the community users will vote to close and close the posts for the correct reason. We will be happy to close a flagged post after reviewing it, but the more balance on the load of work the better.